# Array in Tuple.of (vert.x pgclient)

Tags: rest, vert.x

this is my postgresql CTE's. Works well with various examples.

```
with vtas_itms as (
    insert into ventas (idafip, tipo_venta, nrodoc_persona, tperso_persona, nrodoc_vendedor, 
                      tperso_vendedor, idfinanciacion, cancuotas, fecha_comprobante, punto_venta,
                      numero_comprobante, cae, fecha_vtocae, situacion_fiscal, nombre_cliente, 
                      numero_remito, coeficiente, bonificacion, obs_generales, obs_comerciales,
                      obs_afip, estado)
               values (6, 'Efectivo', 17412018, 'Cliente', 14808837, 
                       'Vendedor', 1, null, '2020-10-27', 6,
                       215, '70332083246226', '2020-11-02', 'Consumidor Final', 'Consumidor Final',
                       null, null, null, null, null, 
                       null, 'Pagada')
    returning idventa
    )
insert into ventas_items (idventa, idarticulo, cantidad, precio_unitario, descuento_articulo, saldo_articulo)
select vtas_itms.idventa, d1.col1, d1.col2, d1.col3::numeric, d1.col4::numeric, d1.col5::numeric
  from vtas_itms
  cross join (values (3,2,82.38,null,null), (4,1,43.12,null,null),(1,0.750,286.30,null,null)) as d1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
```

Pay attention to cross join values: 5 columns with "n" occurrences...it's an array, of course.

Now, on the server side (business):

```
private static final String INSERT_VENTA = "with vtas_itms as ("
            + "insert into ventas (idafip, tipo_venta, nrodoc_persona, tperso_persona, nrodoc_vendedor, tperso_vendedor, idfinanciacion, cancuotas, fecha_comprobante, punto_venta, "
            + "numero_comprobante, cae, fecha_vtocae, situacion_fiscal, nombre_cliente, numero_remito, coeficiente, bonificacion, obs_generales, obs_comerciales, "
            + "obs_afip, estado) "
            + "values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22) "
            + "returning idventa) "
            + "insert into ventas_items (idventa, idarticulo, cantidad, precio_unitario, descuento_articulo, saldo_articulo) "
            + "select vtas_itms.idventa, d1.col1, d1.col2, d1.col3::numeric, d1.col4::numeric, d1.col5::numeric "
            + "from vtas_itms "
            + "cross join ($23::text[]) as d1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)";
```

Look at the $23::text[] parameter...I need to put in the prepared query (after "venta.getEstado()") and in the API...and I don't known how

```
public void putVenta(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        Venta venta = Json.decodeValue(routingContext.getBodyAsString(), Venta.class);
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        pgClient
        .preparedQuery(INSERT_VENTA)
        .execute(Tuple.of(venta.getIdafip(), venta.getTventa(), venta.getNrodoc_persona(), venta.getTperso_persona(), venta.getNrodoc_vendedor(), venta.getTperso_vendedor(),
                venta.getIdfinanciacion(), venta.getCancuotas(), venta.getFecha_comprobante(), venta.getPunto_venta(), venta.getNumero_comprobante(), venta.getCae(),
                venta.getFecha_vtocae(), venta.getSituacion_fiscal(), venta.getNombre_cliente(), venta.getNumero_remito(), venta.getCoeficiente(), venta.getBonificacion(),
                venta.getObs_generales(), venta.getObs_comerciales(), venta.getObs_afip(), venta.getEstado()),  ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .setStatusCode(201)
                        .end();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Failure: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                        response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .end(Json.encodePrettily(ar.cause().getMessage()));
                    }
                });
    }
´´´
API (routes). After parameter /:estado)
```

```
// tag::createRoutes[]
    router.put("/api/ventas/insertVenta/:idafip/:tipo_venta/:nrodoc_persona/:tperso_persona/:nrodoc_vendedor/:tperso_vendedor/:idfinanciacion"
            + "/:cancuotas/:fecha_comprobante/:punto_venta/:numero_comprobante/:cae/:fecha_vtocae/:situacion_fiscal/:nombre_cliente"
            + "/:nro_remito/:coeficiente/:bonificacion/:obs_generales/:obs_comerciales/:obs_afip/:estado").handler(bizVentas::putVenta);
```

```
Any help?. TIA
Ernesto
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to create a virtual table from a single string.

That's actually possible with Postres.

You can provide your string in an array syntax, using `{}`, and then use unnest to split every string into a separate row.

Then you use `string_to_array` to split every row into separate columns.

```sql
select a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]
      from (
               select string_to_array(nest.l, ',') as a
               from (
                        select unnest('{"3,2,82.38,null,null","4,1,43.12,null,null"}'::text[]) as l
) nest) b
```

You can replace your `values ()` part now with this query.

From Vert.x side, you'll have to create exactly this string, and bind it.

Comment: Hi @Alexey Soshin...the CTE's from postgres demand parameters in the correct position. It's impossible join in one cross join all parameters...thanks anyway!

Comment: That's possible, but I didn't understand your question initially.
I'll update my anwer.